# Version Control: Visual Studio Project Support

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

We currently have a number of C++-based products that build under Visual Studio, and are maintained under MKS.

In order for our automated build system (which comprises a number of custom scripts) to increase the version number of the software it must first determine if any of the files within the project have been modified since the previous build.

The current method for performing this check is to check for changes to files in the directory tree below that containing the Visual Studio solution.  This works well enough, but it completely misses those files that reside in other, e.g. shared/common, directories and have been added to the solution as existing items.

I know that this must be a common issue, so I'm wondering what are the usual techniques for managing this sort of thing.  I realise that one option is for there to be no common source files, and instead have shared libraries, but that is quite a long way from the current reality.  What I'm hoping to find out is that for A.N.Other source control system there are plugins that 'support' visual studio solution/project files, and will check for changes in the files included therein.  I think if I had that ability then the problem will go away.

Comment: if you invert the principle you won't have this problem, and it makes more sense: make sure *everything* is in version control, then trigger a build for every change in any of the repositories, and increment the version number for every build.

Comment: Well that's what already happens to apply a 'package' version number, but within that there are individual components that each have individual version numbers.  To be honest I think that the only solution is to have the shared files built in to a shared library that can have a version number itself, and then utilise that library from within the dependent software components.  Thanks anwyay.